# Show html code as rendered html text

Tags: html

I am trying to take some input from the user with the wisywig text editor plugin. But, when I try to show the text in a label or paragraph, all the html tags become visible.
For example,

```
@string str = "<b>sample text</b>";
<label>@str</label>
```

should look like

**sample text**

But it is not. It looks like,

```
<b>sample text</b>
```

How can I render a html code string into a html text...???

i am working with .net mvc3 with razor view engine...

Comment: do you use jquery?. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding/1219983#1219983

Comment: http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/help/examples/01-basic.html

Answer (score 0):

That may happen if HTML entiries are being encoded.

You need to avoid that encoding or do decoding. For example, in PHP you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php to decode HTML entities.

Comment: @dload, well then go ahead and mention it by updating your question. And also include relevant code snippets to make your question clearer.